# Not able to locate the IP address of my Mac ( Not connected to internet yet )

Tags: mac, mac-mini

I am trying to locate the IP Address of my Mac. Used the following command on terminal:

**ifconfig |grep inet**

```
   Output : 
   inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
   inet6fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
   inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff0000000
```

but 127.0.0.1 is localhost.. How to find the IP Address then ?

**ifconfig**

```
VISHWAS-MAC:~ VishwasGagrani$ ifconfig

lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384

inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 

inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 

inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 

gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280

stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280

en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

ether 34:15:9e:2e:b6:c2 

media: autoselect

status: inactive

en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

ether 7c:6d:62:a2:ec:ac 

media: autoselect (<unknown type>)

status: inactive

fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078

lladdr 34:15:9e:ff:fe:2e:b6:c2 

media: autoselect <full-duplex>

status: inactive

en2: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500

ether 7c:6d:62:a2:e6:15 

media: autoselect

status: inactive
```

Comment: Are you connected to a network at all?

Comment: What about the entire output of `ifconfig` could you post that? What network connections are activated, and which networks are you connecting to? (Finally, why would you need to find out the IP address of your Mac that way and not through System Preferences?)

Comment: At first i tried to use "About This Mac"==> More Info ==> Network. But ip address doesnot show at all. It's blank!

When i go to SystemPreferences => Network => Airport(on) , i get a list of wireless internet networks as my ISP told me. I chose one and submitted the required password, but it doesnot connect. On further enquiry from ISP, they told me to provide the IP Address of the Mac. As they require it to give further permissions to my machine. I will paste the content of ifconfig soon.

Comment: added the output of ifconfig also.

Answer (score 0):

If its not a requirement that you use the terminal you should jump into System Preferences>Network. On that page it will show you your IP aswell as the network your connected too.

Comment: Ya.. tried that, but it doesnot show any ip address there. :(